# Is there a way to fix the exponent imaginary number problem? (Python)

Tags: python, math, exponent

So I am doing some math stuff with python, but it seems like every time I find the odd root of a small number, it always ends up as a complex number even though it's not.

`(-0.0019846943379453474)**(1/3)` would lead to `(0.06283494142615101+0.10883331104070793j)`
while it should lead to `-0.125669882852` or something around that.

Comment: You could also try [scipy.special.cbrt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.cbrt.html), which handles this correctly.

Comment: You can consider trying [`math.cbrt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.cbrt) in Python 3.11.